# How to pass list from ajax to controller

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a controller like so..

```
public ActionResult Report(List<string> invoiceIds)
```

and I have an ajax call like so...

```
function generateAccountsPayableReports() {
    var ms = $("#msInvoicesAPV").data("kendoMultiSelect");
    var invoices = ms.dataItems();
    var invoiceIds = [];

    invoices.forEach(function (invoice) {
        invoiceIds.push(invoice.Id);
    });

    //invoiceIds = JSON.stringify(invoiceIds); 
    console.log("InvoiceIds: ", invoiceIds);

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/APV/Report",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(invoiceIds),
        success: function (result) {
            if (result) {
                console.log("result: ", result);
            }
        },
        failure: function (result) {
            console.error("result: ", result);
        },
        error: function (result) {
            console.error("result: ", result);
        }
    });
}
```

I have tried everything I could think of:

- data: {'invoiceIds': JSON.stringify(invoiceIds)}
- data: (invoiceIds)
- data: {'invoiceIds': invoiceIds}
- data: JSON.stringify(invoiceIds)
- data: invoiceIds
- data: JSON.stringify({'invoiceIds': invoiceIds})

when I tried this, it passed in the controller but on a single element only..

[image: {'invoiceIds': JSON.stringify(invoiceIds)}]

[image: It was passed on one element only]

nothing seems to work... what am I doing wrong?

by the way the array in javascript are guid

how do I pass it properly?

Comment: `data: {'invoiceIds': invoiceIds}` should work. You may need to JSON encode the entire thing, though, not just `invoiceIds`. Try this: `data: JSON.stringify({'invoiceIds': invoiceIds})`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossanIve tried that while on debug and it is still null..

Comment: it should work correctly for this    data : JSON.stringify({ 'invoiceIds': invoiceIds});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use type as "GET" and not "POST", use "POST" and don't change anything, normally it will work like that
It seems it receive ONE string in your LIST

Comment: with type GET, you pass ONE long string in the URL and it consider as ONE string, with POST, "data" in ajax can be considered as an Array (please vote my answer as positive, thanks)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `List<string>` declare an array of string in the method controller so it should look like this `Report(string[] invoiceIds)` and to the ajax call just bind array to `data:` 
like this 
`data: invoiceIds`

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work at all. Thank you tho.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this way

```
var ajaxData = { invoiceIds: invoiceIds };
```

than passing the data like this way through ajax

```
data: ajaxData
```